# Handling numeric property in React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use controlled components in my React  forms where I'll tie the value of a field in the form to a property of an object I use to collect data -- see below. For numeric fields in my forms, I like using properties of numeric type but I've discovered an unpleasant behavior and want to see how others handle this.

```
// In my reducer, I have this object that I use to collect data

newItem: {
   description: "",
   reward: 0
},


// Then, in my component, I'll tie the input to a property of the object

<input name="reward" type="number" value={this.props.newItem.reward} onClick={e => this.myHandler(e)} />
```

I'll typically set the initial value of a numeric field to `0` which then renders a `0` in the form for the corresponding field. This is a bit unfriendly because user has to first select the value, then type a new one in -- I realize there are keyboard and mouse tricks one can use but most users don't know them and they will simply use the mouse to highlight the value, then type a new one in.

But the real problem I have is that if the user deletes the `0`, we end up with `NaN` being displayed in the field -- see below before and after.

[image]

Other than using a `string` type for my property then parsing it into a number when I need to, what other options do I have to handle this scenario?

Comment: _Other than using a string type for my property then parsing it into a number when I need to_ is what I do in my projects using `parseInt`.

Comment: Yes, I use this too but wanted to see if there's a better way of handling this. Thanks.

Comment: Everthing come from browser is a string.. so evenif you found out any lib, they will be doing the same under the hood with some better check probably..

Comment: @ArupRakshit You're right about that! Just trying to find a clean solution that I can rely on, whether I use a pattern as you're suggesting or a third party solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably get around it by putting a conditional in the value parameter and assigning a default numeric value:

```
<input name="reward" type="number" value={isNan(this.props.newItem.reward) ? 0 : this.props.newItem.reward} onClick={e => this.myHandler(e)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggestion, but maybe you could have a onChange() function wich would look if the current value is a number, if not, set the value to 0?

```
onChange(event){
  if( isNaN(event.target.value) ){
    // do your stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this would work but handling each numeric field with a "special" handler is not very attractive. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the initial value as you are currently doing, you can display a placeholder value like this:
`<input type="text" placeholder="0" ...`
More info from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text). The '0' will disappear when a user clicks on it.

To fix the NaN issue, one way would be to store the value as a string instead of as a number, and make the form a controlled component. This is detailed in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

For example:
The input:
`<input type="text" placeholder="0" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />`

handleChange:

```
handleChange(event) {
    if (!isNaN(event.target.value) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
}
```

This should ensure that only numbers can be entered in the box.